# MYSQL + Select 2 columns - 1 being Unique

Tags: mysql

I have a table like the following:

```
 domainname    english
 www.a.com     apples
 www.a.com     peaches
 www.b.com     oranges
 www.b.com     banana
 www.c.com     watermelon
```

I want to select a random list of domainname and english but where the domainname is unique. for example:

```
 www.a.com     apples
 www.b.com     banana
 www.c.com     watermelon
```

The results need to be random each time.

I've read other examples on this site and tried the following but it doesn't give a unique list of domainnames - eg: they show up twice or more:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(domainname),english FROM table WHERE domainname ORDER BY RAND();
```

Hopeing someone can give some advice.

cheers

Comment: how many fields do you have in table.? just 2 or more..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND()) t
GROUP BY
  domainname
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query  distinct is not working with multiple column name

```
SELECT DISTINCT(domainname) FROM table WHERE domainname ORDER BY RAND();
```

Comment: yes that works but I wanted to select the second column name in the same query...

Comment: Distinct is not supported with multiple columns. you need to use group by clause for it

Answer (score 0):

If the `english` column is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table (or has a `UNIQUE` constraint), you could also use this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
      ( SELECT DISTINCT domainname
        FROM tableX
      ) AS dd
  JOIN
      tableX AS t
    ON t.english =
       ( SELECT tt.english  
         FROM tableX AS tt
         WHERE tt.domainname = dd.domainname
         ORDER BY RAND()
         LIMIT 1
       )
```